# learn information from text and resolve problem using transformers

Tags: tensorflow, transformer, question-answering

Let's imagine that we have some question, like this: "x multiplied by x equals 9. What is x?"
For this easy question answer is +-3. I want to make AI model answer on questions like that.
To train model we have only corpus
Ex:
"If some variable in power one multiplied by itself and equals to some digit, then we have to get root square from this digit in order to find x". Model has to learn some data from text. Model can't just look for answers in text.

How to do model which could answer on this kind of questions?
I'm waiting for some tips.

**UPD:**
I heard that someone had made AI to resolve schrodinger equation. I want to reproduce their work, but for my own tasks ,which are more easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at https://ai.facebook.com/blog/using-neural-networks-to-solve-advanced-mathematics-equations/

Treat to your problem like to MT task. Use transformer.

Comment: You are late, but thank u